# convert php script to python

Tags: php, python, regex

I try to convert a PHP script to Python

```
$texte = file_get_contents("../test/detail-20110503_10");  
preg_match_all("#Acct-Status-Type(.*)Timestamp#Ums", $texte, $blocs); 

$nbBlocks = count($blocs[0]); 

for ($i = 0; $i < $nbBlocks; $i++)  
{

    preg_match('#Acme-Session-Egress-Realm = "(.*)\"#i', $blocs[0][$i], $Session_Egress_Realm);  

    if  ($Session_Egress_Realm[1] == "Ext-9C" OR $Session_Egress_Realm[1] == "Ext-OBS")    
    {

        echo "cool";
    }
}
```

But the file "detail-20110503_10" is very fat (+100Mo) so I have this error when I try to read it.
**IOError: [errno 12] Not enough space**

```
mon_fichier = open("D:/CDR SBC/test/detail-20110503_10", "r")
contenu = mon_fichier.read()
print(contenu)
```

Please someone could help me to convert the PHP script to python?

Comment: "Not enough space" is relatively self-explanatory, is it not?

Comment: the title of the question does not help others to help you. more appropriate titles could have been chosen.

Answer (score 0):

you can read certain length of content by passing a param to `read()` function, like `read(100)`

or you can use `readline()` to get a single line at a time

Comment: Thx taijirobot2. But a last question : i try readlines(138). But it doesn't work. How can i read 138 lines ?